# Enlightened Spirit aura of menace save DC

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, saving-throw

The Enlightened Spirit PrC has a feature called Aura of Menace

> Aura of Menace (Su): A righteous aura surrounds you whenever you fight
>   or get angry. Any hostile creature within a 5-foot radius of you takes
>   a —2 penalty on attacks, AC, and saves for 24 hours or until it
>   successfully hits you. A creature that has resisted or broken the
>   effect can't be affected again by your aura for 24 hours.

Which is very similar to the Archons Aura of Meance

> Aura of Menace (Su): A righteous aura surrounds archons that fight or
>   get angry. Any hostile creature within a 20-foot radius of an archon
>   must succeed on a Will save to resist its effects. The save DC varies
>   with the type of archon, is Charisma-based, and includes a +2 racial
>   bonus. Those who fail take a -2 penalty on attacks, AC, and saves for
>   24 hours or until they successfully hit the archon that generated the
>   aura. A creature that has resisted or broken the effect cannot be
>   affected again by the same archon’s aura for 24 hours.

There's only one main difference. in the Enlightened Spirit version there's no mention of a save DC, except at the end when it says "A creature that has **resisted** or broken the effect can't be affected again by your aura for 24 hours."

How can you resist that of which cannot be resisted?
I've tried looking into the Complete Mage errata but there's no mention of this and to me it looks like they left that by mistake when copypasting from the archon's feature, but i obviously have no proof of this. So, my question is: how should i consider this part of the class feature? And if it does grant a Saving Throw, what should be the DC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct that neither the original material nor the errata provides any further indication of a saving throw against prestige class enlightened spirit supernatural ability **aura of menace** (*Complete Mage* 61) except for that *resisted or* text.

While the ability does bear a resemblance to the supernatural ability aura of menace that's possessed by creatures with [archon traits](http://dndsrd.net/monstersA.html#archon) (*Monster Manual* 16), this DM would rule that because the ability *isn't* the actual archon trait that the enlightened spirit follows its own rules and that the *resisted or* applies only to those creatures who *can* resist the enlightened spirit's ability in some mysterious, unexplained fashion. In other words, this DM would not *change* the enlightened spirit's aura of menace ability so that it *granted* every creature a saving throw.

Nonetheless, a DM that saw the enlightened spirit's supernatural ability aura of menace as a problem—which, honestly, it shouldn't be as it's an awfully conservative ability—could assign it anyway a saving throw, justifying that decision based on the idea that *resisted or* means that the saving throw description was accidentally omitted or just because the DM wants to. The ability would then follow the normal rules for saving throw DCs against a supernatural ability: DC = 10 + half the creature's Hit Dice + the creature's Charisma modifier (also see *MM* 315).